# Highcharts 3 tickPosition 'inside' not working

Tags: highcharts

I wanted to have the tick labels inside the chart and I found the API for it but I can't get it to work.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickposition-inside/)

```
Is there anything I am missing here?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set negative `y` parameter:

http://jsfiddle.net/aFsAb/

```
 xAxis: {
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        labels:{
            y:-10
        }
    },
```

Comment: With negative y value, it will move the x-axis label. What I want is the y-axis values to be inside and above the tick lines. something simliar to http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/cNgrJ/